# mysql socket path os x

Tags: mysql, macos

how do I set the mysql socket path to the default location? So when I go to the terminal and type "mysql --version" I should see the version instead of "command not found"

Comment: If you're getting command not found its nothing to do with sockets. Can I suggest posting on ServerFault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do "mysql5" command exist?

```
ps -ef | grep mysql
```

should provide some more info

Comment: ps -ef | grep mysql
    0 21783     1   0   0:00.02 ??         0:00.02 /bin/sh /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/localhost.local.pid
   74 21855 21783   0   0:14.99 ??         2:03.22 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/localhost.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/localhost.local.pid
  501 41304 41159   0   0:00.00 ttys000    0:00.00 grep mysql

Comment: seems like u don't have mysql-client. try installing that with port

Comment: i just installed 5.160 and it says the same... when i used to have mamp installed i think i created a symbolic link. but now i got rid of mamp and all i want to do is get into mysql from the command line